# Facebook get email not working

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have this piece of code:

```
require_once("php/facebook.php");
    $config = array();
    $config['appId'] = '***';
    $config['secret'] = '***';
    $facebook = new Facebook($config);
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();
    if(!empty($uid)){
        $fbmail = $facebook->api('/me');
    }
```

And I try to get the email with this line:

```
echo $fbmail['email'];
```

However, this won't work. If I use "name" instead of "email" it works fine... The email permission is set, so what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You must have not set the `email` permission while loggin-in the user, instead in the app settings.

To ask for the extra permissions you should add the permissions to your login code just like this-

```
FB.login(function(response) {
   // handle the response
 }, {scope: 'email'});
```

More details: [**here**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#adding)